# How do I set an attribute inside a Jquery dialog box that I created?

Tags: jquery, attributes, dialog, set, modal-dialog

I create a modal dialog box "dialog1".
I load the HTML contents into it using $("#dialog1").load("dialog_contents.htm") 
  which contains a form.
I OPEN the dialog box.

From inside the page that created the dialog box, how can I set the empty ACTION attribute in the FORM tag to "process.php"?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#dialog1 form').attr('action', 'process.php');
```

And probably you need to put this code inside the anonymous function triggered after the remote page has been completely loaded like:

```
$("#dialog1").load("dialog_contents.htm", function() {
    $('#dialog1 form').attr('action', 'process.php');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of other jQuery newbies like me, I'd just like to clarify that when you open a dialog box, it is part of the same page. jQuery transforms the DIV that you define on the page into a dialog box, ie there is no 'remote' page.' I was confused about this until I read another post on StackOverflow which clarified the process for me.

And thanks again to zerkms for helping me out. It saved me a lot of time in experimentation.